# Html button does not inherit height of container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a button with an arrow icon on the right side, which expands to the left when hover on. I have tried many ways to make the background of the arrow on the right to fit inside the button, but it is not filling the height like I wanted to.

HTML(The arrow on the right is a custom font, so just imagine it as an arrow)

```css
.white-button-arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70%;
  height: 75px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
  border: solid 3px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.white-button-arrow-text {
  padding-left: .5em;
  font-family: Friends-UltraBold;
  font-size: 1.7em;
}

.white-button-arrow-icon {
  display: flex;
  //height: 75px;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-size: 2em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.white-button-arrow:hover .white-button-arrow-icon {
  color: #ff5a45;
  padding-left: 10%;
  text-indent: -60%;
}

.white-button-arrow:hover {
  background: #ff5a45;
}
```

```html
<button class="white-button-arrow" style="width: 90%;"> 
   <span class="white-button-arrow-text">
      <b>GOOGLE-MAPS</b>
   </span> <span class="white-button-arrow-icon">l</span> 
</button>
```

I have tried to set the height to inherit, even hard set it to 75px, but still it is coming out like so:
[image]

Here is what happens when I try to use inherit:
[image]

Comment: Couldn't you set the height to 100% and then set the button's overflow to hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Using `height: inherit;` should work.

Add in `box-sizing: border-box;` to ensure height is being calculated from the outermost points of the element.

If this still doesn't work for you it's likely that you have conflicting css

```css
.white-button-arrow {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 75px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;  
    margin: 0;
    background: white;
    border: solid 3px black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  .white-button-arrow-text {
    padding-left: .5em;
    font-family: Friends-UltraBold;
    font-size: 1.7em;
  }
  
  .white-button-arrow-icon {
    display: flex;
    height: inherit;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-size: 2em;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;  
  }
  
  .white-button-arrow:hover .white-button-arrow-icon {
    color: #ff5a45;
    padding-left: 10%;
    text-indent: -60%;
  }
  
  .white-button-arrow:hover {
    background: #ff5a45;
  }
```

```html
<button class="white-button-arrow" style="width: 90%;"> 
  <span class="white-button-arrow-text">
     <b>GOOGLE-MAPS</b>
  </span> 
  <span class="white-button-arrow-icon">l</span> 
</button>
```

Comment: Like I said in the question, inherit does not work, I have edited the question to show what it looks like for me.

Comment: Okay for some reason, height inherit does not work, but height 100% and border box work, I have no idea why, any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: @Phong2902 `box-sizing: border-box;` sets the height to be calculated from the border of the element (outside of the padding & content), the default is `box-sizing: content-box;` which means you set the height of the content to to 75px then padding and border are applied which makes the element larger than the parent.